# Data Extension contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

We've created a DE cataloguedownloads which registers catalog downloads from our website through API. Since we have different catalogues there can be multiple DE entries, each with E-Mail, subscriberKey, FirstName and Lastname. I want to send one email whenever new entries are created with links to all of the catalogues. But how do I get from the DE to the Journey Entry? How do I need to map the DE in Contact Builder?

Answer (score 1):

While working with Journey Builder if you want to make the new entries from Data extensions it is mandatory to link your DE with Contact Builder else it will be a problem in configuring the entry event.

**To link you DE do the following:**

1. Access and navigate through Contact Builder.
2. Create the data extensions you wish to use to store information about your 
   contacts. Use any existing data extensions within Contact Builder.
3. Create the attribute groups you wish to use in conjunction with your contact records.
4. Click the attribute groups and link your data extensions to the contact record.
5. Import the data into your account and ensure your data imported correctly. If you use existing data extensions, you do not have to import any additional information.
6. Begin using your contact information in your other Salesforce Marketing Cloud apps.

You can visit [contact Builder](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/contact_builder/getting_started_with_contact_builder/) for more information.

Comment: If done it exactly how you described until point 4. Instead of a Import I used a smart capture entry event. I can actually see contacts at "contacts accepted" but the journey builder doesn't send an email. Under all contacts the contacts have a e-mail address as subscriber key but not as a attribute. How can I assign the email attribute?